# how to create local python server for neural networks tasks using rest protocol?

Tags: c#, python, rest, neural-network, localhost

i'm working on a kinect project the whole project written in c# but i need a local server to run python script 
1.the main software will send the information of the skeletal joints to python server 
2.python server will guess the gesture using LSTM neural networks and send it back to the software
i found some instructions using Rest API but i dont know how to create this kind of local server which can do this task 
do have any suggestions to create a local python (neural network) server ???

Comment: Please see [ask] in the Help Center. The question or issue is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the flask framework

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/myurl")
def hello():
    value = neural_network(data)
    return jsonify({"key": value})
```

You can just call it at `http://localhost:5000/myurl`